# How do i change the width of the different columns in the add-on table of storybook?

Tags: css, vite, storybook

I have been trying for a few hours and I can not change the styling of the add-ons table in my storybook. I am using `@storybook/react-vite` and `storybook v7`

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXFUc.png)

The Width of name and description is just way to much. It deviates focus from the actual controls, which are the important part here, anyone any ideas?

I have tried using css files, styled components and `@storybook/addon-styling` with no success

Edit: disabling the description is not a good solution, as i want to actually use it, but just with less width.